# What specs are relevant when charging devices with random plugs

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, amperage, charging

I don't have an EE degree so please bear with me.  I can't find the original charging plug for my portable battery for my Ipad/cell phone/etc.  The battery is relatively new.  I've had it since Christmas and only charged it 3-4 times thus far since I only use it for emergencies when I can't find an outlet to charge my phone/Ipad/etc.  I don't know what this battery is made of.

The battery is a Royal PB11000ST.  It says 
Capacity = 11000mAh 
Input: 5V, 2.4A 
Output: 5V, 4.5A

The substitute plug I found that has the same micro-USB connector the battery needs is from my old bluetooth earpiece.  It says 
Input: 100-240V 0.15A 
Output: 5V = 550mA.   
The plug shows something that looks like an = sign but it's not.  I can take a snapshot of it later if needed.

Anyway, I've been charging this battery for probably 8 hrs now but the battery is not even 1/2 full yet (checked the battery and it told me).  I assumed since the input of the battery and output of the plug is the same (5V), and the output of amps of the plug is less than the input of amps of the battery, that it would be ok.  However, since the battery hasn't even half charged yet, it makes me think this is not ok.

Two questions here,

1. Why doesn't the plug charge my battery since the input/output voltage is the same and the amps coming in from the plug (550mA) is less than the input amps (2.4A)?
2. To find a replacement charging plug, what are the specs I should look for?  What specs should I look for so that the battery charges but doesn't overcharge or explode b/c the numbers are too high (like using 10V when it says input = 5V or 10A when it says input = 2.4A)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer.  To the downvoter, what was bad about my question?  What other info do I need to add to future questions to make it more clear?

Comment: I would start by removing that "I don't have an EE degree so please bear with me". There is no requirement to have a degree on this site, nor will you get a break for not having a degree if you ask a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

- Capacity = 11000mAh (11Ah)
- Input: 5V, 2.4A

Charge time = Ah(bat)/A(charger) minimum  from 0% SoC

- if much less time then Ah has degraded from aging.

  - so 11Ah/2.4A = 5h approx or more from transfer losses and less if partly charged
  - thus **11Ah/0.55A= 20h**  (550mA) give or take details on efficiency.

> so **50% SoC in 8 hrs is normal.**

A 20h charge (=1C) and discharge time is near ideal for efficient use of battery and is in fact the duration for which Ah is rated.  Faster use degrades capacity and slower improves capacity.

Answer (score 1):

1: It's because 550mA is much too low to charge such a large battery pack in any reasonable length of time. Its capacity is 11 amp-hours, meaning that at 500mA, it would take roughly 22 hours to charge. You're not going to break it though.

2: Never try to charge at the wrong voltage. However, almost all chargers on the market charge at 5V, and if they're USB, they are required by the standard to charge at 5V (not counting USB PD, but even that starts at 5V and then the device can ask for more if it needs it). Current is more flexible. If the current rating on the charger is too low, it will charge more slowly. If the current rating is too high, it will just take its rated current from it; a 10A rated supply isn't going to force 10A through whatever you plug into it. The device will just take what it needs.

Incidentally, the thing that looks like an = sign is the symbol for "DC". At least, I'm assuming you mean this symbol:
[image: DC symbol]